# How to fix “Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content” in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, code-coverage, render-blocking

have a Joomla website that I wish to make faster, following the indications given by GoogleSpeed Insight page: "Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles." see also: [google insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Feasy-moving.ca%2F)

The goal is to separate the critical resources from the ones that can be deferred, and eliminate the unused code, to speed up the loading of a web page.

I have issue here [font here](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans&subset=latin,greek,cyrillic)

I cant figure it out what should I do. its fonts

Comment: It looks like you've already answered the question in the question itself? "_separate the critical resources from the ones that can be deferred, and eliminate the unused code_"

Comment: May I get explain how to did it or example for it/

Comment: can it solve the problem `<script src="filename.js" async></script>
<script src="filename.js" async="async"></script>`

Comment: Roughly, write the JS which is needed before DOMContentLoaded fires to its own file, and the rest of the script to another file. Load the former normally, and the latter with defer attribute. Remove all unused style declarations from the stylesheets, or divide the sheets in two files, and add the less important sheet to `<head>` after the DOM has been loaded.

Comment: There might be a lot of job when doing this all. You've to consider, is the possibly gained loading speed worth of all the work. Such test reports are just suggestions, and sometimes tests are real nitpickers. If the report says "These improvements will reduce the total loading time by 2.3 ms", you can very well ignore that part of the report.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Ill try it

Comment: I wrote a free plugin that might help you, it's called "too many files" and you can find it on the jed

Comment: was you talking about [link]https://www.fasterjoomla.com/component/ars/?Itemid=481

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: got you thank you sir